# Error in Logging in Retrofit2, Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Platform.log

Tags: android, logging, rx-java, retrofit2, dagger-2

This is my first try in developing a class based on Dagger and RxJava. I created a `NetworkModule` and it contains following code.

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    private static final long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000; // one minute
    private static final long CACHE_TIME = 432000; // 5days

    private File cacheFile;

    public NetworkModule(File cacheFile) {
        this.cacheFile = cacheFile;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideCall() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.VIEWLORIUM_API_URL_BASE)
                .client(getHttpClientBuilder())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    private OkHttpClient getHttpClientBuilder() {
        // Setup caching file
        Cache cache = null;
        try {
            cache = new Cache(cacheFile, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Setup Logging interceptor
        HttpLoggingInterceptor mLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        mLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(ViewloriumApp.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY :
                HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

        // Setup OkHttpClient
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //
                .addInterceptor(mLoggingInterceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new MyInterceptor())
                .cache(cache);

        // Add StethoInterceptor to display server requests/responses in chrome://inspect/#devices
        if (ViewloriumApp.DEBUG) {
            builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public NetworkService providesNetworkService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(NetworkService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Service providesService(NetworkService networkService) {
        return new Service(networkService);
    }

    private class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Customize the request
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .header("Cache-Control", String.format(Locale.US, "max-age=%d", CACHE_TIME))
                    .build();

            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            response.cacheResponse();
            // Customize or return the response
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to integrate `HttpLoggingInterceptor` into `OkHttpClient`. However when I launch the app, I'm getting following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxIoScheduler-2
    Process: com.my.package, PID: 3105
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Platform.log
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:157)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

However, When I'm delete (or comment out) the line, `.addInterceptor(mLoggingInterceptor)` then application works fine and I'm able to get response from server (but I'm not able to see logs).

## Update

This is list of my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    // Network
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'

    // RxJava & RxAndroid
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    // View Injection
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    // Dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    // Logging
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'

    // Image Loading
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Facebook Stetho
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'

    // Testing
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: You might have two different versions of okhttp? Retrofit has transitive dependency of okhttp, I think

Comment: @AaronHe, thanks for the comment, I just added my decencies in case is helpful.

Comment: @Hesam mvnrepository reports that retrofit 2.1 depends on okhttp 3.3, so i suggest you to change logging-interceptor version to 3.3 too

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov you are absolutely right bro. Thanks for the help. Please add your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mvnrepository reports that retrofit 2.1 depends on okhttp 3.3, so i suggest you to change logging-interceptor version to 3.3 too

Comment: I just tested the latest one `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'` and works fine as well. Thanks for the help.